# Change Color through Color Option

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am working on my app. I want to give user few buttons to change color through which they can change colors. The colors are red, blue, purple, yellow, white and original (wanna use the RGB values) 
Whenever a user hits any color option the whole background color of the app changes and sets itself to default so whenever the app is opened the selected color is background color.

Comment: One option is you can have the user selected color in UserDefaults and apply to all backgrounds.  If user changes it will apply to all..  Hope this works...

Comment: If you show us some of your code, maybe we can identify the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [Custum Color Picker](http://www.fabiancanas.com/entry/iphone-color-picker) link an set that color to your requirement